# Amazon Alexa Skill: Save user preferences like API Key not through code

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Within a custom Alexa skill hosted as a lambda service, I need to call an external API with an API key, that changes for each device. So I can't put the URL or the API Key hard-coded into the skill's code.

Whats the best practice to store user settings locally like an API Key for an Alexa skill? I tried to create an intent, where the user can dictate e.g. the API key, but it doesnt really work quite well and is not that user friendly. Unfortunately, I dindt find a way to create some sort of user preferences site, that might be accessabble for example through the Alexa app on the connected iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Each request comes with a User ID that uniquely identifies the owner of the device.  I use that as a filename for an S3 bucket, retrieving that json file on my Launch intent and storing the info in the session vars.  You can store anything you like in the S3 file and retrieve it per user.

There is no way to save any info without writing the code to do so.  When the skill is first loaded, all session vars are empty.  You need to write code to use the user id to lookup necessary info.